# access localhost stopped working after I installed MAMP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, localhost, mamp

I had configured my machine all access localhost I need some accessed "http://*.localhost.com:3000," * - I put the names of some projects and instances.
I needed to run a PHP server and installed MAMP Pro, but after I ran the php server can't access my others servers more. The http://localhost:3000 it works, but when I need to access the http://*.localhost.com:3000 don't work, I've checked in /etc/hosts and everything is ok.

About the project in php, I have finished and even uninstalled MAMP but not back to normal, the problem continues...
My computer is a mac with Snow Leopard.

Does anyone know how to solve? Thanks

my /etc/hosts:

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1  localhost planner.localhost lambitter.localhost.com bolasolta.localhost.com localhost.com seta.localhost.com crieme.localhost.com
255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0  localhost
```

Comment: I know you say it's fine, but what does your hosts file say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you ping any of the subdomains? If so, the problem is with whatever listens on port 3000 not being configured to listen for those domains. In Apache it's vhosts, with RoR I'm not sure.